# Extract html table in r - from a tbody tag

Tags: r, rvest

I have a HTML table that I would like to extract the results in R using `rvest` - simply doing `read_table` doesn't seem to work for me.

When I paste the code into the following website:

https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer?utm_content=cmp-true

I get the expected output. I am just trying to extract the table contents and store them as a data frame.

Expected output:

```
A31008766       TUDELA      SPAIN       U2      31/12/2021      466.775 
A22031355       FRAGA       SPAIN       U2      31/12/2021      425.173 
A60218674       ALDEAMAYOR DE SAN MARTIN        SPAIN       U1      31/12/2021      406.524 
B47304589       VALLADOLID      SPAIN       U1      31/12/2002      375.036 
A30121115       ALHAMA DE MURCIA        SPAIN       U1      31/12/2021      369.029 
F25005398       GUISSONA        SPAIN       U2      31/12/2021      324.131 
A82038548       TRES CANTOS     SPAIN       U1      31/12/2021      312.009 
A43020643       AMPOSTA     SPAIN       U2      31/12/2021      238.341 
B31070584       MELIDA      SPAIN       U1      30/06/2021      226.354
```

When I run the following:

```
  # html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="ContentContainer1_ctl00_Content_ListCtrl1_LB1_VDTBL"]') %>% 
  html_nodes("tbody") %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  .[[1]]
```

I get a strange output. Additionally, the webpage table is structured as:

[image]

I thought about "looping" through the `tr` tags where the data is stored. I.e. in the following image I want `A31008766` and `TUDELA`:

[image]

HTML:

Link to HTML file:

```
[enter link description here][3]
```

Comment: please include the actual html as code using snippet tooling and provide more information regarding "strange output"